# Hide/show composables in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have tried to use the if-else block to check if the task is completed which in turn will either display or hide the progress bar. The only problem is that it displays the progressBar but it doesn't hide it even after the task is completed

Here is the code snippet

```
      @Composable
      fun ProgressBar(isVissible: Boolean){
    if (isVissible) {
        Surface(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxSize(), color = Color.Transparent
        ) {
            Column(
                Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                CircularProgressIndicator(
                    color = appGreen
                )
            }
        }
    } else {
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
    }

}
```

Comment: That means `isVissible` is always `true`, I guess the reason is that `isVissible` is not a state.

Comment: It is a state. I defined and initialized in my viewModel. The thing is that the value of the state is changing but the UI isn't updating.

Comment: How do you call this function?

Comment: I call it this way:
         val uiState by authViewModal.uiState.collectAsState()
        ProgressBar(uiState.progressVisibility)

Comment: The thing is that when I press the button that is supposed to sign In a user the progress Dialog gets displayed but when the task is done it doesn't hide. I stored a boolean value in a variable which gets updated when a user clicks the button and when the task is done. This value is the one that I passed to the function above. The problem is that the UI doesn't get updated when the value changes. It only gets updated when the user click's the button to sign In but it doesn't hide it after that task is done.

Comment: `UiState` is a data class? `progressVisibility` property is `val` or `var`? Is this state always gets updated by creating a new object? Like `uiState = uiState.copy(progressVisibility = false)`

Comment: UiState is not a data class. It is a variable in the viewModel that stores data from the data class as a mutableStateFlow

progressVisibility is var

Yes, it gets updated

Comment: Change to val and update it only by creating and emitting new object.